# Regex VS13: replace backslash

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2013

I want to replace a `\` in a string with `\\\\`:

```
wsmatch Matches;
wstring String = L"\\";
regex_match( String, Matches, wregex( L"(\\\\)" ) );
if( Matches.size() > 0 ){
    regex_replace( String, wregex( L"(\\\\)" ), L"x" );
    wcout << L"Replaced in: " << String << endl;
}
```

It results in the following output:

```
Replaced in: \
```

It seems like a bug in VS13 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, use

```
String = regex_replace( String, wregex( L"(\\\\)" ), L"x" );
```

[image]

Comment: Never say that about yourself. Delete that comment. Things happen.